# What is a difference between solitons and anyons?

Tags: definition, quantum-computer, solitons, anyons

In the article [Creation and annihilation of mobile fractional solitons in atomic chains](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41565-021-01042-8) the authors claim that they prepared 1D [solitons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soliton) which can be used in topological quantum computing. Based on the abstract and introduction, it seems to me that features the solitons show are those of [anyons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anyon).

I know that *soliton* is more broader term for self propagating wave package, i.e. the wave preserves amplitude, energy and shape. Solitons can appear in a mechanical medium as well as in form of EM waves.

Therefore, I am a little bit confused by terminology. What type of quassiparticle the solitons are in this case. Are they special type of anyons? Or are anyons special type of solitons?

[**Cross-posted on QuantumComputing.SE**](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/26962/)